# How do I fit the images with Bootstrap 4.1?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to fit my images exactly in div(col-xl-4). I've tried and stayed in space. You can look at the visual.
https://i.hizliresim.com/mMERz1.jpg

Below my code;

```
<div class="row mt-5 mb-2 border">
            <div class="col-xl-8 custom-min-height">
                <img class="img-fluid mb-0" src="resources/images/image-24.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4 border">
                <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div class="col">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="resources/images/image-20.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="resources/images/image-21.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-4">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="resources/images/image-20.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="resources/images/image-21.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="resources/images/image-18.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below my solution. In you please write your own solutions.
below css styling

```
.img-fitting {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

index.html

```
<div class="row mt-5 mb-3">
            <div class="col-xl-8">
                <img class="img-fluid mb-0 img-fitting" src="resources/images/image-24.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4 pl-0">
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col">
                        <img class="img-fluid img-fitting" src="resources/images/image-20.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <img class="img-fluid img-fitting" src="resources/images/image-21.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-4">
                <img class="img-fluid img-fitting" src="resources/images/image-20.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4 pl-0">
                <img class="img-fluid img-fitting" src="resources/images/image-21.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4 pl-0">
                <img class="img-fluid img-fitting" src="resources/images/image-18.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
```